# Javascript SQLite for Cordova app - search using parameters where a string contains a substring case-insenstive

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, sql-injection, sql-like

In my Cordova app, I need to query a SQLite database and select rows where the value of the column EventName contains a substring. I want to be able to use ? to hold values to avoid SQL injection. I tried this query:

```
SELECT * FROM EventName WHERE 1 = 1 AND lower(EventName) LIKE lower('%?%');
```

This is my JavaScript code that I use to query the database:

```
function searchEvent(onSearch, eventName) {
    // First create the query string
    var params = [];
    var query = "SELECT * FROM Event WHERE 1 = 1";
    if (eventName != null && eventName != "") {
        query += " AND lower(EventName) LIKE lower('%?%')";
        params.push(eventName);
    }
    query += ";";
    console.log(query); // Log the query
    console.log(params); // Log the parameters
    // Then execute query statement
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql(query, params, function(tx, rs) {
            onSearch(rs);
        });
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err); // This statement was executed
    });
}
```

This is the logged query:

> SELECT * FROM Event WHERE 1 = 1 AND lower(EventName) LIKE
>   lower('%?%');

This is the logged paramaters:

```
[ 'myInput' ]
```

This is the error the was returned:

```
{
    code: 5,
    messsage: 'number of \'?\'s in statement string does not match argument count'
}
```

As you can see there is 1 **?** placeholder and 1 input parameter so the numbers **DO** match. I think it is because the **?** is between the single quotes (**''**) so it is thought to be a part of the searched string. How do I fix this?

EDIT:

The  JavaScript statement `"SELECT * FROM Event WHERE 1 = 1" + " AND lower(EventName) LIKE lower('%" + eventName + "%')"` is ok, but I wanna use a method that can protect me against SQL injection

Comment: Instead of using a wildcard such as ? in side the Like why not simply pass the value, I belive that ? parameter works with values suppied in sql statement.

Comment: @IamKarim1992 I am scared of SQL injection attacks. For now I give up on using SQL parameters and just use the normal way `"SELECT * FROM Event WHERE 1 = 1" + " AND lower(EventName) LIKE lower('%" + eventName + "%')"`

Comment: Yes, SQL Injection attacks comes into picture at later stage , what u could do is prevent it by debarring any Special characters in the eventName using RegEx .

Comment: @IamKarim1992 Can you be more specific and/or give links to help me? How does regex help?
[W3S](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) says that I shouldn't use a blacklist of characters because many terms like **;**  and `drop` are used commonly in English

Comment: /^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+$/g  , if u use this regEx to validate your eventName then it would strike out all the special characters "!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-" and u could have all from a-z ,A-Z,0-9 . If u want some special characters then delete them out in  this !@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-  , this way u validate the eventName against the regEx .

Comment: @IamKarim1992 Very nice. Really useful regex

Comment: wait i m giving u a regEx on jsFiddle , So what do i need to write for u to accept it as anser?

Comment: @IamKarim1992 I don't know how to accept a comment as an answer

Comment: u would find a tick ,click it and press the up button, I answered it as discussed . Hope it helps.

Comment: i have also answered a few question related to googlemaps , u are building a soccerEvent app right , find it in my profile those answeres.

Comment: @IamKarim1992 I have lower than 15 reputation so I cannot vote on comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to prevent the `eventName` from SQL injection, check it with regEx validation to include only alphanumneric and whitelist specific special characters `/^[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]*$/`. Also try this regEx `/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*)(+=._-]+$/g`. I do not believe that ? would work with SQL `SELECT` statement, so you need to pass `+eventname+`

Hope it helps.